# How to create a junction table and add index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, junction-table

Below is my code for creating my two tables, and since playlist and song are many-to-many relationships, I go ahead and create a junction table...

```
CREATE TABLE Playlist (
   Id VARCHAR(20),
   [Name] VARCHAR(50),
   Create_Date DATE,
   Username VARCHAR(20),
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
   FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES Users (username)
);  

CREATE TABLE Song (
   Id VARCHAR(20),
   Title VARCHAR(50),
   Genre VARCHAR(20),
   [Length] TIME,
   [Language] VARCHAR(20),
   Album_Id VARCHAR(20),
   Company_Id VARCHAR(20),
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
   FOREIGN KEY (Company_Id) REFERENCES Company (Id),
   FOREIGN KEY (Album_Id) REFERENCES Album (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Song_Playlist (
   Song_Id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   Playlist_Id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Song_Id, Playlist_Id), 
   FOREIGN KEY (Song_id) REFERENCES Song (Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (Playlist_Id) REFERENCES Playlist (Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE  
);
```

However, when I tried to create the junction table, it keeps getting me this error msg:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RESTRICT'.

I am wondering how do I fix this problem, and also if I want to create an index for Genre in the Song table, how do I do it?

Comment: This does not look like MySQL. Are you sure that you are not using SQL Server instead ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I don't think it's SQL Server neither cause SQL Server has `[ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]` there is no `ON DELETE RESTRICT`.

Comment: Yeah, I am using SQL server. Somehow I typed it wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using SQL Server (according to the code and error message), but from [docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Syntax:**

```
| FOREIGN KEY   
    ( column [ ,...n ] )  
    REFERENCES referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column [ ,...n ] ) ]   
    [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]   
    [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]   
    [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]
```

> ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
>   Specifies what action happens to rows in the table that is altered, if those rows have a referential relationship and the referenced row is deleted from the parent table. The default is NO ACTION.

this why you get an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RESTRICT'`, cause SQL Server does not have `ON DELETE RESTRICT`